# Обработка ошибки requests.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть код и он работает

```
......
    try: requests=requests.post(url,data,timeout=(10,10),proxies=proxyDict);
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
         net_error=1
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
         net_error=1
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
         net_error=1
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
         net_error=1

    print(url,data,proxyDict)
    if net_error ==1:
        return 'proxy'
    else:   

        html=requests.json()
        if html=='success':
            return 'GOOD'
        else:
....
```

но периодически возникает ошибка

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "dc.py", line 85, in <module>
>     status_chek=get_date(login,password,proxy)
>   File "dc.py", line 36, in get_date
>     html=requests.json()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
>     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
>     return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
> simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> ```

Я так понимаю, что requests пустой в этот момент.
Как убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: Не называйте переменную названием модуля: `requests=requests.post(` -> `rs = requests.post(`, `requests.json()` -> `rs.json()`. Перед проблемной строкой проверяйте `rs.status_code` и/или `rs.ok`, скорее всего с той ошибкой приходит статус код не 200

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникала при попытке распарсить строку как JSON, думаю, потому что сайт возвращал в формате HTML (например, какую-нибудь ошибку), поэтому вариантом решения проверять значение поля `ok`. Если это не поможет, то нужно обернуть `html = rs.json()` в `try`/`except`

Кст, все исключения из `requests` имеют общего предка `RequestException`, что позволит их все поймать в одном месте

Пример:

```
...
    print(url, data, proxyDict)
    
    try:
        rs = requests.post(url, data, timeout=(10, 10), proxies=proxyDict);
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return 'proxy'
    
    if not rs.ok:
        return f"BAD STATUS CODE: {rs.status_code}"
    
    try:
        html = rs.json()
    except:
        return "INVALID JSON"

    if html == 'success':
        return 'GOOD'
    else:
...
```